# How can I show Bugs by Tag?

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, azure-boards

We have 100 Bugs which are selected in a query based on a tag "A".
Each of these has another tag "X1", "Y2" "bX", these tags could be anything.

We want to show a chart of the Bugs by the latter Tags.

e.g. We want to show a pie chart of number of Bug numbers by the latter tag mentioned above.
Also show the lifetime of the Bugs by the latter tag mentioned above.

I cannot find a widget in Azure Devops Server 2020 that has this functionality to split the Tags.
I'm looking at Power BI but I'm not sure if it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

First set up a query as follows:

[image]

Then add a **Chart for Work Items** widget in the dashboard:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I see this is not in ADO Server 2020.

Comment: Hi, @Hugh Lin. Any way to add a similar chart using one tag only? So bugs with one tag vs bugs with no tag or without that tag?